# Constrained Motion of Connected Particles, Small Calculation Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, geometry

I am looking at this sample problem from Meriam Kraige - Engineering Mechanics Dynamics:
[image: Sample Problem]

When I do the differentiation, I end up with

$\large -2\dot y+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}$ Where is the $\dot x$ coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are differentiating with respect to $t$, and by the chain rule 
$${d \over dt}(f(x)) = {df \over dx}{dx \over dt}={df \over dx} \dot{x}$$

You have just missed the $\dot x$ part resulting from proper application of the chain rule!